# Linq Group By 3 sets

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following entity that would allows multiple services and trading partners for a entity.  Each one of these sets can have a list of applications.

```
        public Entity Entity   { get; set; }

        public Int64? ServiceId { get; set; }
        public Service Service { get; set; }

        public Int64 TradingPartnerId { get; set; }
        public Entity TradingPartner { get; set; }

        public List<Application.Application> FrontDoorApplications { get; set; }
```

How can I get a nested group of

Entities, Their Services, Their Trading Partners, and the Applications lastly.  For example:

```
Entity 1
    Trading Partner 1    
         Service A
            Application 1
            Application 2
         Service B    
Entity 1
     Trading Partner 2

         Service A
         Service B
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you add some code and models?

Comment: Ok I added a bit more context

Comment: Whats the relationship in your source data between `Entity`, `Trading Partner`, `Service` and `Application`. IE things like does a Service know who its `Trading Partner`s are? Also in your expected output you have `Entity 1` twice

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you should have four separate classes, one each for the four entity(*) types you describe.

If so, then each entity class would need to have navigation links to the related data, both child and parent links. Then you'd be able to do this easily with Linq.

For example...

```cs
public class TradingPartner {
  // other properties omitted
  public List<Service> Services {get; set; }
}

public class Service {
  // other properties omitted
  public TradingPartner TradingPartner { get; set; }
}
```

This of course is assuming I understood your question, but given that the code you posted wasn't even a complete class, never mind four classes, I could be wrong.

If this doesn't help, please clarify your code.

(*) By the way `Entity` is a really bad name for an entity, as it's very generic, rather than describing the specific thing that you are modelling. It also adds confusion when describing your models as a whole, as "entity" is usually used in that context.